# Different background band

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to display a background or another depending on two variables: total pages and number page, such as:

- Page 1 - show a rectangle (as a background)
- Page 2 - show a circle; and
- Page 3+ - show a triangle

How should I modify the report template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some defined variables in your report, as PAGE_NUMBER
Use them in the Option "Print when expression" of your element to show it. (see screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Easy and useful, thank you very much.

But I still have a problem: the expression.
I searched like to know the number of pages in the report, and I see that PAGE_NUMBER variable is also used, but modifying the property 'Evaluation time' to REPORT.

But not like putting this property in the window "Print When Expression". I want to put the following condition:
"report_pages>1 && number_page==1".

I hope you can help me, thank you Vlad.

Comment: Try to define new Variable REPORT_PAGES of class Integer. As Reset type choose Report (it is also a default type) and as Variable Expression set $V{PAGE_NUMBER}. I hope it works for you.

Comment: The latter (variable REPORT_PAGES) has not worked for me. Anyway, thank you very much Vlad!